# Displying images stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, gallery

I am doing gallery and I need some help. I have uploaded images to database through website - they are stored in MySQL (names) and in folder called images. What I want is to display (miniatures) them in line and on click enlarge them.

What my code does is displaying miniatures and links them to nothing :/ ...

This is my code:

```
<?php
$hostname_connect= "localhost";
$database_connect= "gallery";
$username_connect= "root";
$password_connect= "root";
$connect_solning = mysql_connect($hostname_connect, $username_connect, $password_connect) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
                                @mysql_select_db($database_connect) or die (mysql_error());

$query_image = "SELECT * FROM gallery_images";

$result = mysql_query($query_image);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<?php
echo '<img alt="gallery" src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="pic-resize" alt=""></a>';
                                    }
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<div id="light" class="white_content">
<?php
echo '<img alt="gallery" src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="" alt=""></a>';
                                            ?>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
echo 'File name not found in database';
}

?>
```

Comment: whats exactly the problem is

Comment: You're storing binary data in MySQL? Or just the path to the image?

Comment: First of all, remove the spaces between attributes and values in your anchor tags.

Comment: @dianuj the problem is that images display as they should but when I clikc on them on the first one will enlarge.

Comment: @Rob W I just store path to image - images are in the folder on server.

Comment: I see the problem... you have multiple `<div id="light">`'s.. you can only have ONE `ID` per page - they have to be unique.  Perhaps you can change the ID via `div id="light_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">` and all JS references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this in a loop:

```
<div id="light" class="white_content">
```

So you will have multiple elements with the same ID and that is not allowed.

Then you try to access them like:

```
document.getElementById('light')
```

Which will give you the first element it finds and not the actual one you want to enlarge (unless it is the first...).

Personally I would use the standard lightbox solution, link your thumbnail to your big image (instead of `javascript:void(0)`) and use the `href` attribute of your link to set the source for the big image using javascript when the thumbnail gets clicked.

**Edit:** An example for the html to get you started:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
  <a href="<?php echo 'images/'.$row["image"]; ?>" onclick="return showImage(this);">
<?php
  echo '<img alt="gallery" src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="pic-resize" alt=""></a>';
}
?>
<div id="light"><img src='' alt=''></div>
```

Now you just have to write the `showImage()` function in javascript that will do the actual work:

- get the `href` attribute of the clicked link;
- set the source of the image in `#light` to that value;
- show the `#light` element.

Comment: But I would have to link them manually which defeats point in what I am trying to do - unless you can suggest automated way to link them together.

Comment: @Fresz If necessary, you do that automatically in your loop, but from what I can see, you are using the same image for the thumbnail and the big image so you could also use the source of the clicked image to set the source of the big image. Either way, you'd only need one loop and not an additional loop to put all your big images in the html as well.

Comment: @Fresz I was assuming you were building this as an exercise. If you're not, I would recommend using any of the many javascript lightbox plugins that are available.

Comment: the problem is linking thumbnail image to big image :( I can manage plugins... I assume that my code is ok a part from double loop.

Comment: @Fresz But they seem to be the same, so that would just be `images/'.$row["image"].'` like the source of the thumbnail.

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
<?php
echo '<img alt="gallery" src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="pic-resize1" alt=""></a>'; 
?>
<div id="light" class="white_content">
<?php
echo '<img alt="gallery" src="images/'.$row["image"].'" class="pic-size2" alt=""></a>';
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
</div>
<?php
}

Comment: @Fresz That's pretty unreadable but as you are still putting elements with a fixed ID in the loop, it can't be right. Note that you only need one element (a `div` with one image for example) for the enlarged image; that should not be in your loop.

Comment: @Fresz I have added the basic html and what needs to be done in js to illustrate what I mean.